# CLOB in Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, oracle

I'm trying to migrate from Oracle to Postgresql database.

I have some clob column types at Oracle DB:

Here is my questions.

1. Is the TEXT type equivelant for the CLOB in ORACLE DB?
2. Are there any risk for directly convert it to the TEXT? I think TEXT limit is 1gb for the POSTGRE and CLOB limit is 4GB in Oracle?

Comment: An Oracle CLOB can be several TB.  (4GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE equates to between 8 and 128 TB.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/limits001.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, TEXT is a good equivalent in PostgreSQL to CLOB in Oracle. But max size for TEXT is roughly 1GB whereas max for CLOB is 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

Almost, a CLOB can be larger (2GB if I'm right) than TEXT: "just" 1GB.

Comment: Are there any other option for to cover clob with the same size in Postgre?

Comment: No; you'd have to use large objects. If you are actually using CLOBs that large, you are probably used to suffering.